# How to close Files.write

Tags: java, io, nio

I am to attempting to create directory and write data into that file. I am trying to use java nio to write file for more efficiently. My doubt is how to close it after write it below is my code. Please advice me.

And is this correct way to create directory and write large data files [200 kb].

```
    java.nio.file.Path path = java.nio.file.Paths.get(filePath);

    try {
        if (!java.nio.file.Files.exists(path)) {
            java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(path.getParent());
            path = java.nio.file.Files.createFile(path);
            path = java.nio.file.Files.write(path, data.getBytes());
        } else {
            java.nio.file.Files.write(path, data.getBytes("utf-8"), 
                    java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.CREATE, java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
    }
```

Comment: Instead of `Files.write`, with Java 11 you can just do it using [Files.writeString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#writeString(java.nio.file.Path,java.lang.CharSequence,java.nio.charset.Charset,java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) which saves you having to call `getBytes`.

Answer (score 6):

1. Closing file

You do not have to close it as the write method itself ensurer's that file will be closed once last byte is written.

As per description of [Files.write()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20java.nio.charset.Charset,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) method.

> Writes bytes to a file. The options parameter specifies how the the
>   file is created or opened. If no options are present then this method
>   works as if the CREATE, TRUNCATE_EXISTING, and WRITE options are
>   present. In other words, it opens the file for writing, creating the
>   file if it doesn't exist, or initially truncating an existing
>   regular-file to a size of 0. All bytes in the byte array are written
>   to the file. The method ensures that the file is closed when all bytes
>   have been written (or an I/O error or other runtime exception is
>   thrown). If an I/O error occurs then it may do so after the file has
>   created or truncated, or after some bytes have been written to the
>   file.

2. Correct way to create directory and write large data files.

It's fine as long as you handle all exception conditions.

Comment: @ Umesh. Can we able to pass File object to write using nio.

Comment: no, there are no such method provided, but you can always write yours

Answer (score 3):

The `Files.write(...)` method "...ensures that the file is closed when all bytes have been written ..", see [Java SE 8 Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-byte:A-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-)

For writing data into a file see [Reading, Writing, and Creating Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)

Comment: @ Thomas, I am using java 7. It will close default in java 7?

Comment: Yes, see: [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,%20byte[],%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...)]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JDK 1.7 onwards, use try-with-resource it will automatically take care of closing of the resource. Eg. `try(initialize your file resource here){}`
Read more about try-with-resource [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: @ Anil, can we able to use java nio in try-with-resource, i tried link. but i did not get.

Comment: @deadend there is even an example given of java nio of the give java doc page, please go through that.